# failed to close batch:[7] Request Timed Out: the request exceeded the user-specified time limit in the request

Tags: go, apache-kafka

It's my first use of [Kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go). I installed everything locally on a clean machine and used the very first two code samples: Produce Messages and Consume Messages as follows. Please note that I just copy-pasted the code from the aforementioned link.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"
)

func main() {

    ProduceMessages()
    ConsumeMessages()
}

func ProduceMessages() {
    // to produce messages
    topic := "my-topic"
    partition := 0

    conn, err := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "localhost:9092", topic, partition)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to dial leader:", err)
    }

    conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second))
    _, err = conn.WriteMessages(
        kafka.Message{Value: []byte("one!")},
        kafka.Message{Value: []byte("two!")},
        kafka.Message{Value: []byte("three!")},
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to write messages:", err)
    }

    if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to close writer:", err)
    }
}

func ConsumeMessages() {
    // to consume messages
    topic := "my-topic"
    partition := 0

    conn, err := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "localhost:9092", topic, partition)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to dial leader:", err)
    }

    conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second))
    batch := conn.ReadBatch(10e3, 1e6) // fetch 10KB min, 1MB max

    b := make([]byte, 10e3) // 10KB max per message
    for {
        n, err := batch.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b[:n]))
    }

    if err := batch.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to close batch:", err)
    }

    if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to close connection:", err)
    }
}
```

However, whenever trying to close the batch session, I am getting the following result (after waiting a bunch of seconds):

```
one!
two!
three!
```

Well, that's nice so far, but this is always followed by the following error.

```
2022/12/10 10:35:50 failed to close batch:[7] Request Timed Out: the request exceeded the user-specified time limit in the request
exit status 1
```

Why is it failing to close the batch (why is it timed out)?

PS> Please note that I'm unable to add the `Kafka-go` which differs from the already existing `confluent-kafka-go` tag

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the size of your **batch** is less than 10 kb.
Try to reduce the value of the first argument in this line:

```
batch := conn.ReadBatch(10e3, 1e6) // fetch 10KB min, 1MB max
```